# Integration of the Euler-Lagrange equation with explicit dependence on x

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

In the variational calculus, if the Lagrangian $L[y(x),y'(x)]$ is not an explicit function of $x$, the Euler-Lagrange equation takes on the following form:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(L-y'\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right)=0\,.$$

This can be integrated to arrive at the Beltrami identity. However, if the Lagrangian depends explicitly on $x$, one has to use the full Euler-Lagrange equation. In this case, it can be recast in a form that is similar to the above, but with nonzero right-hand side:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(L-y'\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\,.$$

I would like to integrate this equation but am not sure how to do it when the left-hand-side contains the total derivative and the right-hand side only a partial derivative. Is there any general solution to this problem, similarly as the Beltrami identity "undoes" the derivative in the first equation above?

Comment: If we integrate $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(L-y'\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\, ,$$
we have $$L(x) = \text{Constant} + y'\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} +\int \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} dx\,.$$

Comment: Thank you, this helps. So, $\partial/\partial x$ will only act on those terms in $L$ that depend explicitly on $x$ and not on those with $y(x)$ and $y'(x)$. This means that the integral (when taken as a definite one) will be some function $F(y,y')$.